# Setting Mongodb Connection Pool Options via mongo-java-driver Java API

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, mongo-java-driver

Using Morphia and mongo-java-driver, I'm connecting to a mongo server:

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
        builder.sslEnabled(true);
        builder.sslInvalidHostNameAllowed(true);
        builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(0);
        MongoClientOptions sslOptions = builder.build();

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(serverAddressList, Arrays.asList(mongoCredential), sslOptions);
```

Where serverAddressList is the **host:port** list and mongoCredential using kerberos auth are created as:

```
MongoCredential mongoCredential = MongoCredential.createGSSAPICredential("user@REALM.COM");
```

I want to setup a custom Connection Pool Parameters using:

1. maxPoolSize
2. minPoolSize
3. maxIdleTimeMS etc.

To achieve this I found **ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder** and **com.mongodb.connection.ConnectionPoolSettings** Classes.

I searched a sample code [here](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=frederikhappel/activecheck/activecheck-master/activecheck-reporter-mongodb/src/main/java/org/activecheck/plugin/reporter/mongodb/MongodbReporter.java):

```
ConnectionPoolSettings connectionPoolSettings = ConnectionPoolSettings
                .builder()
                .minSize(MIN_MONGO_POOL_SIZE)
                .maxSize(MONGO_POOL_SIZE)
                .build();
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings
                .builder()
                .readPreference(MONGO_READ_PREFERENCE)
                .credentialList(credentialsList).clusterSettings(clusterSettings)
                .connectionPoolSettings(connectionPoolSettings).build();
```

Can someone please suggest a way of applying these settings to get an Instance of MongoClient ?

Libraries which are being used:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:3.4.3'
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally figured out the correct way of setting the connection pool parameters, so answering my own question here.

I browsed the source code for MongoClientOptions [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/3.4.x/driver/src/main/com/mongodb/MongoClientOptions.java#L134)
where the connectionPool parameters are being set as follows:

```
connectionPoolSettings = ConnectionPoolSettings
                    .builder()
                    .minSize(getMinConnectionsPerHost())
                    .maxSize(getConnectionsPerHost())
                    .maxWaitQueueSize(getThreadsAllowedToBlockForConnectionMultiplier()
                    * getConnectionsPerHost())
                    .maxWaitTime(getMaxWaitTime(), MILLISECONDS)
                    .maxConnectionIdleTime(getMaxConnectionIdleTime(), MILLISECONDS)
                    .maxConnectionLifeTime(getMaxConnectionLifeTime(), MILLISECONDS)
                    .build();
```

We can see that the minSize and maxSize values are being fetched from `getMinConnectionsPerHost();` and `getConnectionsPerHost();` methods. So to change and customize the connection pool parameters at client code we can simply add maxConnectionIdleTime and minConnectionsPerHost values to the builder as follows:

```
MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = MongoClientOptions.builder();
    builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(0);
    builder.minConnectionsPerHost(50);
    builder.connectionsPerHost(200);
    MongoClientOptions sslOptions = builder.build();
```

This code successfully opens up the minimum specified connections to the mongodb server host.

```
LOG : 00:20:00,714 INFO  [org.mongodb.driver.connection] (pool-1-thread-1) Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:50}] to server.com:27180
```